# How build my own Application Setting

Tags: java, design-patterns, configuration

I want to build a `ApplicationSetting` for my application. The `ApplicationSetting` can be stored in a properties file or in a database table. The settings are stored in key-value pairs. E.g.

```
ftp.host = blade
ftp.username = dummy
ftp.pass = pass
content.row_pagination = 20
content.title = How to train your dragon.
```

I have designed it as follows:

Application settings reader:

```
    interface IApplicationSettingReader {
    Map read();
}

DatabaseApplicationSettingReader implements IApplicationSettingReader {
    dao appSettingDao;

    Map read() {
        List<AppSettingEntity> listEntity = appSettingsDao.findAll();
        Map<String, String> map = new HaspMap<String, String>();
        foreach (AppSettingEntity entity : listEntity) {
            map.put(entity.getConfigName(), entity.getConfigValue());
        }

        return new AppSettings(map);
    }
}

DatabaseApplicationSettingReader implements IApplicationSettingReader {
    dao appSettingDao;

    Map read() {
        //read from some properties file 
        return new AppSettings(map);
    }
}
```

Application settings class:

```
AppSettings {
private static AppSettings instance = new AppSettings();
private Map map;

private AppSettings() {
}



public static AppSettings getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Object not configure yet");
    } 

    return instance;
}

public static configure(IApplicationSettingReader reader) {
    this.map = reader.read();

}

public String getFtpSetting(String param) {
    return map.get("ftp." + param);
}

public String getContentSetting(String param) {
    return map.get("content." + param);
}
```

}

Test class:

```
AppSettingsTest {
    IApplicationSettingReader reader;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        reader = new DatabaseApplicationSettingReader();
    }

    @Test
    public void  getContentSetting_should_get_content_title() {
        AppSettings.configure(reader);

        Instance settings = AppSettings.getInstance();
        String title = settings.getContentSetting("title");
        assertNotNull(title);
        Sysout(title);
    }

}
```

My questions are:

1. Can you give your opinion about my code, is there something wrong ?????
2. I configure my application setting once, while the application start, I configure the application setting with appropriate reader (`DbReader` or `PropertiesReader`), I make it singleton because the application just have one instance of ApplicationSettngs. The problem is, when some user edit the database or file directly to database or file, I can't get the changed values. Now, I want to implement something like `ApplicationSettingChangeListener`. So if the data changes, I will refresh my application settings. Do you have any suggestions how this can be implementedb ????

Comment: have you seen jakarta commons config? It supports reading configuration from many sources, including properties and db. http://commons.apache.org/configuration/. In the same space, is also jfig - http://jfig.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How would you know if the settings file changed? The file / database will not tell you if they have been changed on disk. You will need to implement a mechanism to automatically check for changes of those config files on disk in specific intervals yourself. (e.g. modification times, token, last updated entries etc.)

Comment: @mdma. I never try that, I will check it. can I ask question to you ? is the configuration library support run time changed ?

@futureelite7, yes. the file or database dont tell me the data has been changed. based on your suggestion, I can create thread application, that check the configuration periodic. according to you, how long the interval ? so I can get the fresh configuration if i access my application? according to me, I must check it every time, is that efficient ?

Comment: I agree with mdma. commons-configuration also has suport for detecting configuration changes. I also suggest you not use a singleton. In general singletons make code less testable and reusable.

Comment: why I use singleton, Application only have One ApplicationSettings, it's not good to have multiple configuration for application. So I used singleton. why did you said, singleton make code less testable and reusable ? thanks

Comment: I do not know your requirements, but if they are as easy as you stated, than I think you have a bit of overdesing - are entity and dao required?

Comment: It's depends on the ApplicationSetting reader, because the reader is DatabaseApplicationSettingReader, I use DAO to find all application settings from the application tables. The applicationSettingsEntity represent one row of applicationsettings tables. this is the one that you ask for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't throughly inspected your code, but there seems to be a concurrency issue. The map is thread-unsafe (HashMap), so if you mutate it through config() and have other threads access map, you have a problem.

Though you could use a `ConcurrentHashMap` instead `HashMap`, a batch operation on `ConcurrentHashMap` is not atomic. Meaning that, if you use it, you will see a "half-way" modified config. That could not be okay depending on your app.

So, the solution for this is to use this:

```
private volatile ImmutableMap map;

public config(){
    ImmutableMap newMap = createNewMap();
    this.map = newMap;
}
```

This will change your configs atomically (no intermediate state is visible).

As for updating your config on the fly, log4j does it using a background thread that monitors the config file. You could of course monitor a db table instead by polling it periodically.

In that case, your Config class will have preferably a ScheduledExecutor with a task that will monitor files/db and call config() periodically.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to question #2 is to use a thread and check periodically if the file has been changed or to simply reinitialize your settings with the file contents.